# Increase radius in make_circles method of sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

In Python sklearn is possible to create a circles dataset in a box [-1,1]. I am wondering if it's possible to increase the radius of the circles, for example inside a box of [-5, 5] or [-10, 10]

```
from sklearn import datasets
X, l = datasets.make_circles(n_samples=1000,
                                 shuffle=True,
                                 noise=0.08,
                                 random_state=42,
                                 factor=0.8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply multiply the circles by the radius you want. For example, for a radius of 5:

```
X5 = X*5

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], label = "original")
plt.scatter(X5[:,0], X5[:,1], label = "radius=5")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]